# Enviar un formulario hecho con Livewire a una ruta en específico

Tags: php, html, laravel, livewire, routes

Supongamos el siguiente caso:

Copmonente:

```
class Formulario extends Component{
    public nombre = "";
    
    public function render(){
        return view('vistas.formulario');
    }
}
```

Formulario blade:

```
<form action="{{ url('/mi-ruta') }}">
    <input wire:model="nombre"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

El problema es que cuando le doy click al input de envíar, los datos no se envían a la ruta, simplemente se recarga la página, y me gustaría no utilizar "wire:submit" para envíar datos... algúna idea? gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías redefinir el envío de los datos quitando el form.

```
class Formulario extends Component{
    public nombre = "";
    
    public function store(){
      $this->nombre;
    }

    public function render(){
        return view('vistas.formulario');
    }
}
```

```
<div class="contenedor">
 <input wire:model="nombre"/>
    <button wire:click="store">
       Enviar
    </button>
</div>
```

Aunque sinceramente no le veo mucho caso a no querer usar wire:submit